# JSF 2 ajax behavior event listener not firing on a Date

Tags: jsf-2

I am having a problem with an ajax behavior event not being fired immediately as text is typed in a field.

If the field is a String no problem, but I am using a Date.

xhtml:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Date of Birth:" />
<h:inputText id="searchDOB" value="#{search.dob}" required="true">
  <f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{search.addHyphensToDOB}" render=":output" />
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" />
```

bean:

```
Date dob;

public void addHyphensToDOB(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe) {
  System.out.println("addHyphen");
}
```

The event is only fired after typing the following:

> 22-JAN-

And fires on any number after the second hyphen, but not before.

One solution could be to change the Date type to a String, then format without using converter, but I would like to keep the Date type.

Any suggestions, thanks.

Eclipse 3.7, tomcat 7, jsf2.1,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fired because a conversion error has occurred due to invalid date format. The submitted value is converted everytime before the bean listener method is hit. Add a `<h:message>`/`<h:messages>` and include its ID in `<f:ajax render>`. You'll then see it.

A `String` value of for example `2` can impossibly represent a valid `Date` object when parsed with the pattern `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

You'll really need to keep it a `String` if you want to achieve the functional requirement this way. As a completely different alternative, you could consider to do it entirely at the JavaScript side without sending JSF ajax requests.

Comment: I think client side validation will be best.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, is it solely for validation? You can also just perform it on change or on blur instead of on key up.